# Quick-release for battery terminal loops (D18S/T3)

Tags: battery, wiring, boat

I have a [D18S/T3](https://ajcbattery.com/product/ajc-12v-18ah/) battery that I want to use to power the lights of an aluminum boat.

[image]

I don't want to leave the battery in the boat when I'm not using it. I figure the elements would damage the battery over time. So I want to easily remove the battery after each use and store it elsewhere.

So far, I've been using nuts and bolts to attach the wiring [ring terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOTrc.png) to the battery. But unthreading the bolt each time to disconnect the battery is tedious.

Is there such a thing as a quick-release mechanism for this style of battery terminal? Something more secure than flimsy [alligator clips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY5sU.png), possibly similar to a [bicycle quick-release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi9w4.png) mechanism?

---

*For bonus points, what is that style of battery terminal called?*

Comment: Also posted as https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29074/quick-release-for-boat-battery-terminal-loops

Comment: I stumbled onto some bicycle-style quick-release batter clamps on Amazon. But they're for the wrong kind of battery terminal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FwSa.png —  https://www.amazon.ca/weideer-Connectors-Terminals-Connector-Disconnect/dp/B09BTZS45D/ref=sr_1_4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consult your favorite search engine for 12V Quick Connect to find a multitude of possible solutions such as this one:

[image]

[Photo credit](https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/connect-ease-12v-lawn-tractortrolling-motor-8-gauge-connector-kit)

Comment: You beat me to it :o) Exactly what I was going to post.

Comment: An inline fuse sized to protect the wires and connectors would be a good addition as well. Don't want the Anderson Powerpole welding together on a short circuit. Available with weather covers to reduce water ingress...